# .Net 6.0 AuthorizationContext.Controller equivalent

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I'm migrating some old ASP.NET MVC 5 code to .NET 6.0 and having some trouble with an `AuthorizationFilter` that, within its `OnAuthorization` implementation, accesses the decorated method's controller class instance, like this:

```
// Get the decorated method's name
string actionName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;

// Get the controller instance and then, its type
Type controllerType = filterContext.Controller.GetType();
```

I just can´t see how I would get the controller instance (or event the method's name) from the `AuthorizationFilterContext` available in .NET 6.0. Any help?

Comment: where are you executing that on custom ActionFilter or AuthorizationFilter?

Comment: @Laxmikant, AuthorizationFilter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create new class

```
public class LogEntry : IAuthorizationFilter
{
 public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
 {

 var controllerActionDescriptor = context.ActionDescriptor as 
        ControllerActionDescriptor;
  
 string controllerName = 
     controllerActionDescriptor?.ControllerName;
            string actionName = 

 controllerActionDescriptor?.ActionName;
        
 }
}
```

In Program.cs register LogEntry class

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<LogEntry>();
```

on controller action method

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(LogEntry))]
public IActionResult Index() 
{
   return View();
}
```

[image]